# MemoryCache with AbsoluteExpiration stored in an IOC container using .SingleInstance()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, autofac, memorycache

I have an abstraction over the `MemoryCache`, this instance uses `AbsoluteExpiration` for its `CacheItemPolicy` and is managed by Autofac as follows:

```
builder
    .RegisterType<MyCache>()
    .As<IMyCache>()
    .SingleInstance()
    .WithParameter("cacheName", "MyCache");
```

Theoretically I want the items to expire absolutely (e.g. in 15 minutes).

The problem (question) is, that it's a single instance over all request and no mechanism in place that resets the expiration to 15 minutes in the future again.
So the refresh would only happen a single time, right?

What's the solution for this? Do I need to hook into an event or something...?

Comment: can you post the code for MyCache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I need to specify a certain point in time where the cache key expires:

```
AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15)
```

The cache policy was being set in a `private readonly field` which only gets initialized when creating an instance of `MyCache`, but this only happens on application startup (IoC container, single instance).

This works for me now:

```
private CacheItemPolicy CachePolicy => new CacheItemPolicy
{
    AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15)
};
```

Everytime the cache item policy is accessed, a new `DateTimeOffset` is calculated.

Answer (score 1):

Cache item policies work on a per item basis. Add an item, it expires 15 minutes later (based on your item policy). There's no "reset" or anything required. It doesn't work like a timer or semaphore - add stuff, cache handles the rest.

You can test this by making the policy sufficiently short (a minute?) adding stuff, and waiting.

Comment: Yeah, but my problem was that I need to specify a certain point in time where the cache key expires: `AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15)`. The cache policy was being set in a private readonly field which only gets initialized when creating an instance of `MyCache`, but this only happens on application startup (IOC container, single instance). This works for me now: `private CacheItemPolicy CachePolicy => new CacheItemPolicy { AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15)... };`. Everytime the cache item policy is accessed, a new DateTimeOffset is calculated.